# Is it possible to set non-cluster-exclusive environmental variables for a scheduled job in Databricks?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, configuration, databricks

I'm currently in charge of several Databricks scheduled jobs that were all created by somebody else. These jobs all use environmental variables. The problem is, I do not know where these env variables are being defined. I know that one can generally set environmental variables while creating the job cluster, however, these env variables later appear within the job's JSON configuration file. The jobs I'm talking about all have environmental variables, none which are included within their JSON config file. Furthermore, there aren't any init scripts defined, as it could be the case that said variables were defined within such script. The only thing I can think is that maybe there is an option to set "global" environmental variables that can be accessed by every cluster within the Databricks workspace, but I have yet to confirm this nor have I seen anything while going over the Databricks Admin Console. Does anybody have an idea about what could be going on?

Comment: what specific environment variables are used?

Comment: An example of such an env variable would be "ENVIRONMENT", resolving to either "dev" or "prod" depending on the workspace. However, there are quite more env variables regarding JDBC hosts, usernames, etc...